# Update Android SDK manager without Internet Connection but by earlier downloading for another SDK

Tags: android

Lets say there are many pc s and each pc has Android SDK installed.And one pc updates its SDK because it has internet connection.In this way, all downloads are installed that SDK directly. I want to know whether there is a way to download SDK updates as a separate file (and not directly update the SDK) and other pc s(which have not internet connection) are updated with that downloaded file. (In other words download one update and share it among other pc s and update all pc s by one downloaded file)

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the platforms folder from the sdk directory..[image]

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep. only copying the platform folder and pasting into other SDK(or replacing the platform folder) will provide the updates and solve the issue completely?