# Why do some Android APIs do not show up in the AVD Manager Target Tab?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, android-virtual-device

I've to work in an environment which has no internet connection due to security reasons. I've downloaded the latest APIs and following the steps in the below answer, have them in my

```
..\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms
```

[Update Android SDK manager without Internet Connection but by earlier downloading for another SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147942/867591)

Altough, I can see the APIs in the SDK Manager as installed, when I go to the AVD Manager they don't show up in the target.

Only the Android 4.2 API (which came preinstalled with the ADT/Eclipse bundle (Android Developer Tools) shows up. But one thing I noted was that in the SDK Manager, it had two files (SDK Platform and ARM EABI v7a System Image) while others had only the SDK Platform file.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse after downloading the APIs?

Comment: Never thought it would be that simple! Thank you so much! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you restarted Eclipse after downloading the APIs? :)